# How to add row margin while inflating a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Linearlayout part of a Tablerow of tablelayout. Below is sample description

```
<!-- Master Layout-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="0" android:baselineAligned="false">
<TableRow>
<Button></Button>
</Tablerow>

<TableRow>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/listinfo"></LinearLayout>
</Tablerow>
```

Then I wrote another linearlayout to create rows of linearlayout which I inflate and add to
linearlayout of Main Layout.

```
<!-- listrow layout-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/textView1" />

        <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/textView1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything is working perfectly fine but I am not getting row demarcators. How to do that?

Java code

```
LinearLayout placeHolderLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listinfo);

for (int i =0; i < myarray.size(); i++) {

  final Employee eobj = myarray.get(i);     
  LayoutInflater vi =         (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  LinearLayout lrow = (LinearLayout)vi.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null); 
  lrow.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);   
  lrow.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);   
  ((TextView)lrow.getChildAt(1)).setText(eobj.getName());    

   //some more settings
   placeHolderLinearLayout.addView(lrow);

 }
```

The view doesn't show any demarcator between subsequent linearlayout. How can I achieve that?

```
  |---------------------|
  |  lrow1              |
  |______demarcator_____|  
  |  lrow2              |   => The demaractor is missing in my view
  |_____________________|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LinearLayout lrow = (LinearLayout)vi.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);
```

Try to pass `placeHolderLinearLayout` instead `null`.

If you define `true` as third parameter the infalted layout will be added automatically to the given `ViewGroup`. `false` will avoid that.

Comment: My problem is not that. All views are getting added properly but I am not able to see margins between two subsequent rows. There is no demarcation between two rows, they also don't overlap looks perfectly ok but I want some demaracation.

Comment: 1. There is not a single margin definition in your examples. 2. Which margin are you talking about then? which view do you expect to have maregins (i assumed you mean the root `LinearLayout` in your second XML layout code)

Comment: By margins I meant row demarcators. Yes the root LinearLayout in which I am adding lrows doesn't show any demarcators between two subsequent rows. I will explain it pictorially in my questions.

Comment: If you mean that the defined margins from the mentioned `LiniarLayout` has no effect, then my solution will do the trick. By defining a parent view group the infaltor will infalte also the margin definition.

Comment: Yes I can see row margins now. Thanks. Also is there a way I can make this rows elliptical rather default rectangular?

Comment: Glad I could help. I have no idea what you mean because views have always rectangular layout, but I won't discuss it here because this is not the initial question.